# Import text file signal data in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Have tried to understand how to import text file data (time signal) in Matlab, can you please help. Structure of .txt file looks like this:

0,0006  0,0835
0,0013  0,0016
0,0019  0,0082
0,0026  -0,0193
0,0032  0,1115
0,0039  -0,1169
0,0045  0,0461
0,0052  -0,1185
0,0058  0,0048
0,0065  0,0087
0,0071  -0,1163
0,0078  0,0913
0,0084  0,022
0,0091  0,0072
0,0097  -0,0829

in original file it looks like to column separated by tab space:

[image]

Comment: I presume you use commas rather than decimal points, so you have 2 fields on each line and the first one is time with 600microseconds sample rate?

Comment: I believe so it is, it is not know how data are stored. I believes so sample rate is 1600.

Comment: Could you edit the question with the text data as text instead of as an image, so we can copy-paste it to test possible answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution:

```
A = importdata ('text_file_neme.txt');

M = A(:,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace commas by dots and use dlmread function:

```
cat signal.txt
0.0006 0.0835
0.0013 0.0016
0.0019 0.0082
0.0026 -0.0193
0.0032 0.1115
0.0039 -0.1169
0.0045 0.0461
0.0052 -0.1185
0.0058 0.0048
0.0065 0.0087
0.0071 -0.1163 
0.0078 0.0913 
0.0084 0.022
0.0091 0.0072
0.0097 -0.0829
```

```
format long
data=dlmread('signal.txt',' ',0,0)
data =

   5.999999999999999e-04   8.350000000000000e-02
   1.300000000000000e-03   1.600000000000000e-03
   1.900000000000000e-03   8.200000000000001e-03
   2.600000000000000e-03  -1.930000000000000e-02
   3.200000000000000e-03   1.115000000000000e-01
   3.900000000000000e-03  -1.169000000000000e-01
   4.500000000000000e-03   4.610000000000000e-02
   5.200000000000000e-03  -1.185000000000000e-01
   5.800000000000000e-03   4.800000000000000e-03
   6.500000000000000e-03   8.699999999999999e-03
   7.100000000000000e-03  -1.163000000000000e-01
   7.800000000000000e-03   9.130000000000001e-02
   8.399999999999999e-03   2.200000000000000e-02
   9.100000000000000e-03   7.200000000000000e-03
   9.700000000000000e-03  -8.290000000000000e-02
```

Disclaimer: I don't have MATLAB on my computer and therefore used Octave. Based on my previous experience, it should work in MATLAB as well.

Comment: It's possible that the aim of the question was to determine if there is a way to handle the commas in Matlab.  For example, if the script will be used repeatedly to read files of similar type or the files contain many rows, they may be looking for an approach that automatically recognizes the commas as periods.

Comment: It can be easily done - just requires some effort.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using three steps:

```
file_string = fileread('my_file.txt');       % Read file contents to string.

file_string = strrep(file_string, ',', '.'); % Replace commas in string to periods.

file_mat = str2num(file_string);             % Convert contents to a matrix.
```

The original questions states that the columns are separated by tab and it appears that the rows are separated by a line feed in the figure, but in the text, rows are also separated by tabs.  If the file uses line feeds to separate rows, then the result `file_mat` will already be formatted into rows and columns.  If tabs are used to separate all elements (columns and rows), then `file_mat` will contain a vector only.  If this is the case, then `file_mat` can be reshaped using the following:

```
file_mat = reshape(file_mat, [2 length(file_mat)/2])'; % Convert vector to array with two columns.
```

This was verified as below:
[image: test result]

Comment: Thanks, after file_mat = str2num(file_string); matrix is created by no values in it.

Comment: I have added test results to the answer.  You can see that the input file my_file.txt contains the same tab-separated values as above.  It might be helpful to provide the exact file being used for the test.